# What criteria does Magento follow to order by "Best Value"?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, category

I have the option "Best Value" by default but all products are in position 1. With each product in position 1, what criteria does Magento use to sort them? Is it random?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**  I uploaded a new product to test it, and it appears at the 53rd position. All products are in position 1. So my question is, why the new product isn't the first product in the category? What is the criteria? This is so confusing!

Comment: It will display based on updated date in database.

Comment: it will sort product as per "position" in category. if you are checking in "ASC" order it will be displayed at 53 position. and if you check it in "DESC" it will be first position if 53 is highest  position in that category.

Comment: Yeah but every product has the same position: 1. Why does the new product appear at 53?

Comment: check in both ASC and DESC order

Comment: ASC sort it from lower to higher and DESC sort it from higher to lower

Comment: Yes, I did that and I still can't see what's the criteria Magento is using when all products are on the same position "1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all products have the same position value think it will be sorted by  product id. EDITED: It won't be random.